# Unable to append svg element to svg root

Tags: javascript, xml, events, svg, mouseover

I would like to add a text element to my existing svg using a mouseover event. I think the code works fine in general but I'm unable to append my created text element to the existing svg file (root). I tried to do it in a way I could also find it right here on stackoverlow, but it doesn't work for me.
Neither `var root = doc.documentElement` nor `var root = doc.rootElement` works. Also it makes no difference using svgNS or null while creating the elements.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
    <![CDATA[function showText(evt) { 
    var doc = evt.target.ownerDocument; 
    var root = doc.documentElement; 
    var text = doc.createElementNS(null, "text"); 
    text.setAttributeNS(null, "x", "10"); 
    text.setAttributeNS(null, "y", "30"); 
    text.setAttributeNS(null, "font-size", "12"); 
    var textNode = doc.createTextNode("test"); 
    text.appendChild(textNode); 
    root.appendChild(text);  
    }]]>
</script>
```

Complete code of my svg:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="stroke:black" height="600" width="800">
  <rect width="800" x="0" y="0" height="600" style="fill:none" />
  <rect width="800" x="0" id="textbox" y="540" height="60" style="fill:none" />
  <rect width="720" x="40" y="30" height="480" style="fill:none" />
  <line y2="510" x1="40" x2="760" y1="510" />
  <line y2="510" x1="40" x2="40" y1="30" />
  <text font-size="12" x="40" y="530">Time (X)</text>
  <text font-size="12" x="5" y="20">Data (Y)</text>
  <polyline style="stroke:black;fill:none;" points="91.84,217.19189757859385 143.68,323.2917668597486 195.52,235.86502103932202 247.36,43.359991864346625 299.2,202.8 351.04,315.903272925833 402.88,160.41241257803188 454.72,157.66691947582518 506.56,387.2047460928005 558.4,183.60000000000002 610.24,260.73963745895736 662.08,59.445816214522495 713.9200000000001,283.88097314947527 "
  stroke-width="2" />
  <script type="text/ecmascript">
    < ![CDATA[function showText(evt) {
      var doc = evt.target.ownerDocument;
      var root = doc.documentElement;
      var text = doc.createElementNS(null, "text");
      text.setAttributeNS(null, "x", "10");
      text.setAttributeNS(null, "y", "30");
      text.setAttributeNS(null, "font-size", "12");
      var textNode = doc.createTextNode("test");
      text.appendChild(textNode);
      root.appendChild(text);
    }]] >
  </script>
  <circle id="circle" text="Dies ist ein Test" r="10" cx="400.0" onmouseover="showText(evt)" cy="510">Dies ist ein Test</circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG elements must be created in the SVG namespace so you want this:

```
var text = doc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
```

You also can't have spaces in the CDATA begin/end section markers which your code snippet has (but your original code excerpt does not).

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately it makes no difference. edit: Okay, namespace just in this line - still unused in "text.setAttributeNS" and it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Works for me locally with that/those change(s) assuming I run it as a standalone SVG file. It won't work as a stack snippet as the root element is the html page there.